# App Engine API Android client

Tags: android, python, google-app-engine, channel-api

I'm looking for a client version for android to use the appengine channel API on my app. I've seen some other people developed, but none of them seems stable. Some have to use a web view for the JavaScript, etc. I don't want something like that.

Any resource about it, or any wise approach I could use?

By the way, I'm using appengine with python.

Answer (score 1):

There's and official [C2DM service](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/) to receive updates from the cloud on mobile devices, which works in a way similar to channels, by opening a socket and listening for updates. Is there any reason why you don't want to use C2DM?

Comment: well, mainly because of the quota limits, also, the users must be logged to their google account, and a bunch of restrictions. but, If I dont find any resource, I'm gonna use C2DM.